# Is there a way to merge big query hyperloglog sketches outside of big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to export the hyperloglog sketches from big query and merge them on the outside for cardinality estimation. Is there an open source library available that can readily parse the big query sketches?

If not, is there any publically available information about the format of biq query's hyperloglog sketches? Specifically, which hashing algorithm is used, what type of meta-data is contained, and how the sketches are structured?

Comment: Anyone not familiar with HYPERLOGLOG sketches should read this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate-aggregation#storing-estimated-aggregate-values-as-sketches

Answer (score 1):

The details of the sketch format and hashing for the HLL_COUNT family of functions is not public at this time.

Could you file a feature request on the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149) with more details (e.g. what tools/langs/libraries are would you prefer to interoperate with for cardinality estimation)?

Comment: Just for reference. There are currently two open tickets regarding this question: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117087375 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123269269

Comment: Current status is that the creation of new "BigQuery-HLL++" sketches in Apache Beam is under development: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7013

Answer (score 0):

Now you can achieve this using ZetaSketch (https://github.com/google/zetasketch), which includes an implementation of HLL++ algorithm that is compatible with Google Cloud BigQuery's implementation.